# Write a program that uses a loop to take 3 key-value inputs from the user and create a dictionary using these keys and values

Tags: python

I'm very new to learning programming. I'm starting with Python.
Do you know the solution to this problem?
That's the closest output I can get...

My attempt:

```
my_dict={}
for items in range(1,4):
    key=str(input('enter string'))
    value=int(input('enter #'))
    my_dict={f'{key}: {value}'}
    print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{'gregory: 34'}
{'perry: 84'}
{'sinatra: 76'}
```

Expected Output:

```
{'gregory': '34', 'perry': '84', 'sinatra': '76'}
```

I don't know how to get everything on the same line...

Comment: Create a Dictionary

Program Description
Write a program that uses a loop to take 3 key-value inputs from the user and create a dictionary using these keys and values.

Create an empty dictionary named my_dict.
Use for loop to iterate from 1 to 3, including 3.
Inside the loop, take inputs for key and value and store them in my_dict.
Print the updated my_dict.
Example
Test Input

gregory
34
perry
84
sinatra
76
Expected Output

{'gregory': '34', 'perry': '84', 'sinatra': '76'}

Comment: Move your `print` statement out of your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict={f'{key}: {value}'}
```

This creates a *brand new* dictionary, because you're reassigning the name `my_dict`.

You don't want this; you want to add this key-value pair to the *existing* dictionary.

Use this instead:

```
my_dict[key] = value
```

And then move the print statatement below the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see! Thanks for your help! :)

```
my_dict={}
for items in range(1,4):
    key=str(input('enter string'))
    value=str(input('enter #'))
    my_dict[key]=value
print(my_dict)
```

It worked! yay! I also had to make both variables strings to get the quotation marks.

Comment: `input()` already returns a string.  You don't need `str()`.

Comment: Please don't answer your own question unless you actually have a new answer. If you have feedback for an answer you can comment below it. Remember to also accept an answer if it solves your original question. Keep follow ups separate by asking new questions.